# How to receive an array from a HTML page on Flask back-end

Tags: python, html, flask

I'm taking inputs in a HTML window and storing it in an array using JavaScript.
I want to return that array to to my Flask server.

```js
function createTable()
{
    var name = new Array();
    cn = window.prompt("Input number of features", 1);
    for(var c=0;c<cn;c++)  
    {
        fname = window.prompt("Input feature name", 1);
        name[c]= fname;
    }
}
```

```html
<form action = "/data", align="center"> 
<button  class="btn btn-success"  STYLE="background-color: #800080;" onclick ="createTable()">Enter 
Details</button></a>
</form></body>
```

I'm using the following line to fetch it on Flask:

```
feature_names = request.form.get("name")
```

However, it does not seem to be working for me. I want to know if there is a way to get arrays from HTML to Flask.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `request.form.getlist('name[]')` in your Flask application.